# Hide free shipping for specific shipping classes exclusively in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shipping-method

We have a large variety of products in WooCommerce, some of which are not our own and supplied. I am trying to set up a functionality where free shipping is disabled if the products in the cart belongs to "Extra" shipping class  **exclusively**.

If there are any other products with it that are not in the shipping class 'Extra', free shipping would still apply. So if 5 products are in cart all with shipping class 'Extra' and no other products, there is a $5 charge. If there is any other product that is not in that shipping class, free shipping applies again.

I've scoured the internet for solutions and this is what I got so far:

```
function hide_shipping_methods( $available_shipping_methods, $package ) {
    $shipping_classes = array( 'Extra', 'some-shipping-class-2' );
    $excluded_methods = array( 'free_shipping' );
    $found = $others = false;
    $shipping_class_exists = false;
    
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $key => $value )
        if ( in_array( $value['data']->get_shipping_class(), $shipping_classes ) ) {
            $shipping_class_exists = true;
            break;
        }else {
            $others = true; // NOT the shipping class
            break;
        }
    if ( $shipping_class_exists && !others) {
        $methods_to_exclude = array();
        foreach( $available_shipping_methods as $method => $method_obj )
            if ( in_array( $method_obj->method_id, $excluded_methods ) )
                $methods_to_exclude[] = $method;
        if ( $methods_to_exclude )
            foreach ( $methods_to_exclude as $method )
                unset( $available_shipping_methods[$method] );
    }
    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
```

However it doesn't seem to be working. I have products already in the shipping class **Extra**, however whenever I add them to cart there is still free shipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes and your code can be simplified. To disable free shipping for specific shipping classes **exclusively**, try the following revisited code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_free_shipping_conditionally', 10, 2 );
function hide_free_shipping_conditionally( $rates, $package ) {
    // Define the targeted shipping classes slugs (not names)
    $targeted_classes = array( 'extra' ); 
    
    $found = $others = false; // Initializing
    
    // Loop through cart items for current shipping package
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        if ( in_array( $item['data']->get_shipping_class(), $targeted_classes ) ) {
            $found = true;
        } else {
            $others = true;
        }
    }
    
    // When there are only items from specific shipping classes exclusively
    if ( $found && ! $others ) {
        // Loop through shipping methods for current shipping package
        foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            // Targetting Free shipping methods
            if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
                unset($rates[$rate_key]); // Remove free shipping option(s)
            } 
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Doin't forget to empty your cart to refresh shipping cached data.

Comment: Thank you! This is getting rid of the free shipping option, however the $5 charge from the shipping class isnt showing up. Is there a way to force a 5$ charge instead of the free shipping please?

Comment: @apaandmomo So that mean that you need to be sure that you have a flat rate in your shipping zones, with a shipping rate of $5 for "Extra" shipping class. My code has no effect on other shipping methods like "Flat rate" and/or "Pickup".